# Change margin background color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

There is a margin for outlining items on the left side of editor window in visual studio 2010. Is it possible to give it a different background color?
"Different" means: another color than the color of main part of editor window.

I had disabled outlining mode and track changes. So I have no orientation where to click with mouse to select first column of a row.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, looked high and low in Tools>Environment>Fonts and Colors. Can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010, you could change the color of **Track Changes after save** and **Track Changes before save**

> ```
> Tools -> Options -> Enviornment-> Fonts and Colors-> Display Items -> Track Changes after save / Track Changes before save
> ```

Comment: I had *disabled* the _Track Changes_. So I don't know why these settings can help. My current settings are _green_ for _Track Changes after save_ and _yellow_ for _Track Changes before save_.